# Why does SSMS v18.11.1 Import Wizard truncate decimals?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms

Why does SSMS v18.11.1 truncate decimals that are read in as a float?

This screenshot shows that there are decimals in the values imported from a tab delimited text file. [decimals in the values imported from a tab delimited text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QV5eW.png)
[image]

This screenshot shows that the decimals were truncated in the table
[This screenshot shows that the decimals were truncated in the SQL Server Import process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRO1B.png)

[image]

Is there another datatype I can use besides float to keep the decimals from getting truncated?

Comment: There's no such SQL Server version. Are you confusing SQL Server, the database, with SSMS, the client tool? Neither truncates fields. What is the table definition? What is the column type? If you create an `int` or `decimal(18,0)` column the stored values will be truncated no matter what tool you use

Comment: Also post examples of the source and table data. For all anyone knows you may be looking at the wrong rows. Drawing a red line over the numbers hides nothing except hide the actual problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the Data Type is set to float in the Advanced tab of the Choose a Data Source dialog box and also make sure the destination column is a Float in the Column Mappings window (if the table is new)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the numeric data type value? that says it has a precision of 18, I think I used that in the past as float was removing values after the decimal point.

[image]

Comment: You would need to set Scale to something other than 0 to allow values after the decimal point